# ReportViewer's ReportParameter in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5, ssrs-2012

I am working on a solution where we have to show the filter data of ReportViewer in MVC application. We have SSRS reports hosted in SSRS server. I am able to show the report viewer in MVC application. On top of this, we need to filter the data's  in the **ReportParameters** based on the user's permission. Since we dont want to store the copy of .rdlc file, we cannot alter the **reportparameter** list as it is a **readonlycollection**.

Is there a way we could apply the filter

Comment: Can you post what you have tried

Comment: Tried creating a custom type and partial view so that I have more control over the data. As of now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding a hidden parameter to the report that will be used by the parameter dataset list for filtering and that way you can control it by code. Check this article regarding parameters and filtering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder

Regards

Comment: I created a wrapper type with required attributes. Then I generated dynamic parameter controls using partial view. Since I dont want to re-invent the wheel, is there any libraries available?

Comment: Do you refer to a library for parameters generation?